# This volume has 75.8 MB used space. You can’t remove this volume, because the preceding volume cannot be resized. This volume can’t be resized

Tags: bootcamp, partition, disk-volume

[image]

I want to make a replacement parition for bootcamp purposes, any way to help?

Comment: Edit your question and add an image of the pie chart with the partition marked with the "*" selected. Also, add the output from the command `diskutil list`. I assume you want to remove the BOOTCAMP partition. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is to back things up and then erase the disk. If you have more knowledge of command line tools, editing in the information requested from the comments would likely get a less obvious answer but it might not require the erasure of the disk.

Also - if you edit in what specifically you tried or why you can't make progress - we can try to meet you where you are instead of offering the basic / easy way forward from a skills / documentation standpoint. Apple offers great documentation on backup, erase, install from a clean start with BootCamp (imo).

Comment: How do i back it up, i don't know coding and all

Comment: Hi @JerrySeinfelter - if the top two hits here don't work you can ping us again. [No need to code anything to use Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250)